# How to filter tid.length using v-if on html list

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How can i only let tid length 7 at level **one** and tid length 10 go to show at level **two**. I tried to use v-if to make as filter but only show the level **one**, but level **two** doesn't show.

Tid

[image: Tid]

Current problem

[image: Current Problem]

Treelist

[image: Treelist]

What I'm looking for

[image: Example]

https://ibb.co/GdPf8yd  << Example Tid

Example : level one `8000001` so under will be `8000001000, 8000001001, 8000001002, 8000001003, 8000001004`

```html
<template>
  <div class="css-treeview">
    <template v-for="item in treelist" :key="item">
      <ul>
        <li v-if="item.t.length == 7"><input type="checkbox" id="item-0" /><label for="item-0">{{ item.mAcName }} ---
            {{ item.mName }}</label>
          <ul>
            <li v-if="item.t.length == 10"><input type="checkbox" id="item-0-0" /><label for="item-0-0">{{ item.mAcName }}
                --- {{ item.mName }}</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: can you please share the `treelist` data. so that it will be easy to understand and can you please also tell what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: @RohìtJíndal hi i updated the treelist,  I am using the **t** as checking when the **t** length is 7 will be on level one if **t** length 10 the data will be at level two. I updated the example you can check it.

Comment: I think you should solve this with the backend. IF existed

Comment: @Amini Thanks for the detailed description. Now, I got your requirement but the problem here is how do you will know `level 2` will go inside which `level 1` ? As we have a flat array and it will iterate with `v-for`, how do you will know under which level1 you have to put level 2 ? also as per the condition, 2nd condition is inside the first condition. Hence, it will never get execute.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal thanks for the remind, so to know which level 1 under level 2 by using last character of **t**, you can check the image here >>> https://ibb.co/GdPf8yd

Comment: Example : level one 8000001 so under will be 8000001000, 8000001001, 8000001002, 8000001003, 8000001004 https://ibb.co/GdPf8yd

Comment: @Meow Are you sure ? It means the 7 digit `t` will always contain a unique character at the end ? It will mean we will have only `0-9` total `10` t in the whole array of objects which contains 7 digits ?

Comment: @RohìtJíndal there will 13 digit **t** which will be level three and more. So the system is 7digits = level one, 10 digits = level two and more. The digit is fixed and the last character of **t** is to check under who.

Answer (score 1):

This condition always returns 'false' because there is no overlap in the types '7' and '10'.

you should do like this.

```
<template>
  <div class="css-treeview">
    <template v-for="item in treelist" :key="item">
      <ul>
        <li v-if="item.t.length === 7">
          <input type="checkbox" id="item-0" /><label for="item-0">{{ item.mAcName }} --- {{ item.mName }}</label>
          <ul>
            <template v-for="item2 in treelist" :key="item2">
              <li v-if="item2.t.length === 10">
                <input type="checkbox" id="item-0-0" />
                <label for="item-0-0">{{ item2.mAcName }} --- {{ item2.mName }}</label>
              </li>
            </template>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I tried the code but the item2 is getting loop more than one times...  check this image >> https://ibb.co/Xks8YjF

Answer (score 0):

As stated in @O-h-y-0 answer, the problem with your code is that the "if" clause is overlapping.

The "if" clause checking for length 10 will never be executed since it is wrapped with an "if" clause limiting for length 7.
But the problem with his answer is that the second loop will execute in every parent so that it will appear duplicated.

My advice is to create a computed variable, where inside it you regroup the item with with length 7 as a parent and move the item with length 10 as the children. For example, I have this simple data.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in treeGrouped">
        {{item.value}}
        <ul>
          <li v-for="child in item.children">
            {{child}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        treelist: [
          'aaaaabb',
          'aaaaabbbbb',
          'aaaaabb',
          'aaaaabbbbb',
          'aaaaabbbbb',
          'aaaaabb',
          'aaaaabb',
          'aaaaabbbbb',
          'aaaaabbbbb',
          'aaaaabbbbb',
          'aaaaabb',
        ]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      treeGrouped() {
        const result = []
        this.treelist.forEach((item)=>{
          if (item.length === 7) {
            result.push({
              value: item,
              children: [], 
            })
          } else if (item.length === 10) {
            if (result.length) {
              result[result.length-1].children.push(item)
            }
          }
        })
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

This logic on computed only apply to that simple data I make, because it too long to replicate your data since you only provide example data as an image. But if you understand what I mean, I'm pretty sure you can improve it to your needs.

Edit:
For reference, those logic on computed will give you something like this.

```
[
  {
    "value": "aaaaabb",
    "children": [
      "aaaaabbbbb"
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": "aaaaabb",
    "children": [
      "aaaaabbbbb",
      "aaaaabbbbb"
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": "aaaaabb",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "value": "aaaaabb",
    "children": [
      "aaaaabbbbb",
      "aaaaabbbbb",
      "aaaaabbbbb"
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": "aaaaabb",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

Comment: so its list store level one to the list1 and push list2(store level two) to list1 ?

Comment: yes, loop the source array, if you catch id with length 7, push it to result array and create an empty array variable on it to contain the children. if you catch id with length 10, push it to the children of the last array of result.

Comment: if you need and you don't mind to JSON.stringify your json to provide example data, I can help you to modify the code based on your data.